# Right to Left form with XLForm in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, right-to-left, xlform

I have two questions:

1. How can I create a Right to Left form in XLForm (Right label and
   Left TextField or other widgets) I tried to get the label or text
   field frame but that wasn't helpful.
2. How can I create a multi valued table with reorder and delete
   actions that last button perform a segue and then the result creates
   a new row. Assume I want to add multiple pictures and the last row
   of table is "Add New" button. but my problem is a delete sign will
   appear at the left of that row too. On the other hand I don't want
   to add a row like a text filed but I want to set a segue result as
   new row.

Comment: Were you able to change direction of XLForm from L2R to R2L?

Comment: no it hasn't default feature for that but you can set your application locale to fa so your entire app become RTL so the form works correclty